# Different behaviour in Instantiation of class in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, object, instance

Recently I have been experimenting with classes and objects & got stuck in one doubt. I tried googling but I didn't understand what to search of this. Below is the code snippet.

```
class Demo:
    def __init__(self):
        print("In init")

    def __call__(self,item):
        print("Got {} in call".format(item))

    def print(self):
        print("Evaluating print()")
```

Now after completing the above program I tried the following few commands as below :

```
>>>a=Demo
>>>a.print()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Python Shell, prompt 3, line 1
builtins.TypeError: print() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
>>>a.print(a)
Evaluating print()
>>>b=Demo()
In init
>>>b.print()
Evaluating print()
>>>type(a)
<class 'type'>
>>>type(b)
<class '__main__.Demo'>
```

My Questions in this case are :
1) What is the difference between `a=Demo` and `b=Demo()` while creating objects?
2) Why `a.print()` didn't work in the first case but `a.print(a)` is working fine?
3) In this case `b('item')` will work to give output as `Got item on call` which doesn't work in case of `a('item')`. Why is it like this?

NOTE :: I am using Python 3.6 for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a=Demo` doesn't create any objects, it merely assigns the `Demo` class object to the variable `a`.

You actually show this yourself:

```
>>>type(a)
<class 'type'>
>>>type(b)
<class '__main__.Demo'>
```

In Python, classes are also objects that have the type `type`.

Compare what happens when you use `a` by replacing `a` with `Demo`.

Note, classes are first class objects, you can treat them like any other object, like a `list` or an `int`. `type` is actually just a constructor, like `list` and `int`:

```
>>> list()
[]
>>> int()
0
>>>
>>> MyClass = type('MyClass', (), {})
>>> MyClass
<class '__main__.MyClass'>
>>> MyClass()
<__main__.MyClass object at 0x10406fe80>
>>>
```

The type constructor takes three arguments the name of the class as a string (note, you don't *have* to assign it to the same variable name), a tuple of bases, here's it's empty so it is implicitely `object`, like if you did `class A: pass`, and the *namespace*, so a mapping from attribute names to attributes. Methods are just function objects that belong to the namespace of the class

```
Init signature: type(self, /, *args, **kwargs)
Docstring:
type(object_or_name, bases, dict)
type(object) -> the object's type
type(name, bases, dict) -> a new type
Type:           type
```

Here's a slightly less trivial example of a class created with the `type` constructor that also has methods:

```
>>> Foo = type('Foo', (), {'__init__': lambda self, x: setattr(self, 'x', x), 'bar': lambda self: self.x})
>>> f = Foo(42)
>>> f.bar()
42
```

Read more in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type)

Comment: So it's more like creating an alias for the Demo class object..?

Comment: @DibakarBose Yes. *every* assignment in Python is like creating an alias. Note, class objects *are first class citizens* in Python. Just like functions, they can be assigned to a variable, re-assigned to any other variable, passed as a function argument, returned from a function etc

Comment: I see.. Now I understand.. Thank you

Comment: @DibakarBose I updated with some more information you might find enlightening